# Haskell - Either Map Only One

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I want to write a function which consumes an `Either` value, and two functions. It applies only one of the functions based on which one is compatible with the inner type. Totally struggling with implementing this one.

```
mapAorB :: (x -> z) -> (y -> w) -> Either x y -> Either z w
```

Comment: pattern matching could be your friend here....

Comment: No problem with doing it for learning, but for production use, you should be aware that `Either` is a [bifunctor](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bifunctors/docs/Data-Bifunctor.html) so this is just `bimap` at `Either`.

Comment: I used bheklilr help below, but seem to be getting some errors if maybe you could help me out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start by writing out all the arguments to the function

```
mapAorB :: (x -> z) -> (y -> w) -> Either x y -> Either z w
mapAorB xz yw eitherxy = undefined
```

Then determine if any arguments can be matched on.  Here, only `Either` can be.  Expand the argument into pattern cases:

```
mapAorB xz yw (Left x) = undefined
mapAorB xz yw (Right y) = undefined
```

By the specification for the function, we know that if we input `Left x` then we'll get `Left z`, and similarly if we input `Right y` it'll return `Right w`.  That gives an extra hint:

```
mapAorB xz yw (Left x) = Left z where z = undefined
mapAorB xz yw (Right y) = Right w where w = undefined
```

So how would you define `z` and `w`?

Comment: Now what we have left to do, is check the inner type if its capable and then map?

Comment: @TeodoricoLevoff That's what `Left` and `Right` do, they select the type of the contents.  The definition of `EIther` is `data Either a b = Left a | Right b`.  The contents in `Left` can only be of type `a`, and the contents in `Right` can only be of type `b`.

Comment: Ah right, so then what is left is to map the Either value to the function. Something like, ... = Left z where z = xz x, I think I butchered the syntax, but I want to map the Either value to that function for both Left and Right.

Comment: @TeodoricoLevoff You're on the right track, I'll say that.

Comment: So, like mapAorB xz yw (Left x) = Left z where z = xz x                                             mapAorB xz yw (Right y) = Right w where w = yw y . bheklilr, based on the steps done, we started off pattern matching checking both the left and right if the inner type is compatible, and then the next step is to do the map part? I can't see anymore steps. Also, is the syntax for calling the map correct? Thanks

Comment: @TeodoricoLevoff Try it out.  You can use it as `mapAorB f1 f2 (Left someValue)` or `mapAorB f1 f2 (Right anotherValue)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72448/discussion-between-teodorico-levoff-and-bheklilr).